# Writes that the reference to the object does not indicate an instance of the object, although all values are assigned

Tags: c#

Writes that the reference to the object does not indicate an instance of the object, although all values are assigned.
I have already tried everything and I have no idea how to fix this error.

```
public enum blocks
{
    air,
    ground
}

static blocks[][] layer1;
static blocks[][] layer2;
static blocks[][] layer3;
public static blocks[][][] layers;
public static void Start()
{
    layer1 = new blocks[7000][];
    layer2 = new blocks[7000][];
    layer3 = new blocks[7000][];
    for (int y = 0; y < 7000; y++)
    {
        layer1[y] = new blocks[7000];
        layer2[y] = new blocks[7000];
        layer3[y] = new blocks[7000];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 7000; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 7000; y++)
        {
            layer1[x][y] = blocks.air;
            layer2[x][y] = blocks.air;
            layer3[x][y] = blocks.air;
        }

    layers = new blocks[3][][];
    layers[0] = layer1;
    layers[1] = layer2;
    layers[2] = layer3;
    Player player = new Player();
    Console.WriteLine(layers[1][1][1]); //output: air
    try
    {
        GameMain.text.text = layer1[1][1].ToString(); //error happens here
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: If you have an error message, please include it.

Comment: What is the `GameMain.text.text`? Are these properties initialized?

Comment: Please show the definition for `blocks`, especially any `override string ToString()` method. Likewise, please show how `GameMain` and `GameMain.text` are initialized.

Comment: Please explain what `GameMain.text` is, and how you are making sure that it is not `null` (because chances are that it is null).

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski GameMain.text.text is string value of my UIText class. This always works well, except in this case.